# Parallel execution with data provider

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to run the test parallel using dataprovider. I have mentioned `dataproviderthreadcount=3` in testng xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="3"parallel="methods">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.sample.test">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Test methods:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "dp1", threadPoolSize=3,invocationCount=1)
public void Testsuitesample(String url, String add1, String add2){}
```

Result: 3 browser instances get opened and all three data is passing to only browser. Other browser's are still idle. Is it a way to resolve this?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Result: 3 browser instances get opened and all three data are passing to one browser.Other browser's are still idle. is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: set parallel=true in dataprovider method. it may solve your issue.

Comment: Can you share your actual test method code or some similar sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set parallel to true in your data provider method like,

```
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
public Object[][] dp1() {

}
```

Also, the invocation count should be equal or greater than the thread pool size.

Comment: @DataProvider(parallel = true) - it is already set . I have set the invocation count and thread pool size as mentioned. But No luck. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Madhu - Please edit your question and add proper sample code which demonstrates the problem. The code you have shared shows no information around the problem that you are talking about. (There is no browser instantiation logic etc., shown)

Comment: @Test(dataProvider = "dp1", threadPoolSize=3,invocationCount=1)
public void Testsuitesample(String Browser, String url, String add1, String add2){ 
       OpenBrowser(browser);                                                                 
       LaunchURL(url);                                                                    
 }.

Comment: can you add the code for dp1 method? and invocation count should be greater than or equal to threadPoolsize

Comment: @Murthi@DataProvider(parallel = true) - it is already set . I have set the invocation count and thread pool size as mentioned. But No luck. Still facing the same issue. – Madhu 2 days ago

Comment: As per your code, You set invocation count to 1. it should be 3 or >3

Comment: @Murthi,I have tried all the possibility. No luck.. Do you know how add a parameter "dataproviderthreadcount" in cmd prompt

Comment: yes, you can pass the parameter like mvn -Ddata-provider-thread-count="6" test

Comment: java -cp D:\backup\Sample\lib\testng-6.8.jar;D:\backup\Sample\lib\jcommander-1.27.jar;D:\backup\Sample\lib\*;D:\backup\Sample\target\classes; org.testng.TestNG testng.xml -dataproviderthreadcount 2

Comment: @Murthi No... it is not userdefined